# regex, I want to return (n) values in a submatch

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex, that I want to extract from a text some template tags with (n) parameter:

```
\{{2}([\w\-\d]+)([\s:\,]*(?:\[([\w\%]+)\])*)*\}{2}
```

But the problem is the above regex returns only the last parameter, and I want to catch all parameters. This parameters also can repeat multiple times. I can't see what is wrong. Somebody can help me?

Exemples:

```
Exemple 1 {{url-builder: [linktitle], [email]}} // Return ['url-builder', 'email']
Exemple 2 {{url-builder: [linktitle]}} // Return ['url-builder', 'linktitle']
```

Exemple 1 should return ['url-builder', 'link-title', 'email']

To be more specific, I have the follow text

> Ao contrário do que se acredita, Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente um texto randômico. Com mais de 2000 anos, **{{url-builder: [linktitle], [email]}}** suas raízes podem ser encontradas em uma **{{author-name}}** obra de literatura latina clássica datada de 45 AC. Richard McClintock, um professor de latim do Hampden-Sydney College na Virginia,

From the above text, I want to catch all tags {{tag}}. But some tags can have parameters {{tag: parameter-1}}, and these parameters can repeat multiple times {{tag: parameter-1: parameter-1}}. I'm trying to catch a single array with the tag and all parameters.

Comment: What regex flavour/tool/programming language do you use? How are you extracting the capturing groups from your match result?

Comment: I'm using php to parse a newsletter template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, capturing groups usually store only the last occurrence of their pattern. You can wrap all parameters in one group to get them:

```
\{\{([\w\-]+):\s*((?:\[[\w\%]+\][,\s]*)*)\}\}
    ^       ^    ^                      ^
```

Then afterwards split that by `/[,\s]+/` to get a list.

Comment: It seems ugly to use two regex to catch the tags, but, if the capturing groups store only the last occurrence of their pattern, I have nothing else to do. thank to help.

Comment: @user2434945: They don't in all regex engines. Depending on your programming language, there might a method to access the earlier matches as well. I'm not sure about PHP, check the docs.